# How to specify version for dependencies so that each one is compatible and stays within a size limit?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torch, library, fastai

I am trying to deploy a web app to Heroku. The free tier is limited to **500 MB**.

I am using my resnet34 model as a `.pkl` file.

I create model with it using the fastai library.

This project requires torch and torchvision as dependencies.

But not specifying the dependency will download the latest version of torch which alone is **750 MB** and exceeds the memory limit.

So, I specify torchvision version as `0.2.2` and specify the wheel for torch for `v1.1.0` in the requirements.txt file. Now, this gives rise to other problems.

For example, I got this error message from Heroku build log-

> ERROR: torchvision 0.2.2 has requirement tqdm==4.19.9, but you'll have tqdm 4.48.0 which is incompatible.

But if I specify tqdm's version to `4.19.9`, some library called `spacey` becomes incompatible and the app fails. If I install more recent version of torchvision, the app size will exceed permitted limits.

How do I get around this problem? How do I find out which dependency versions are compatible with each other, and the total size doesn't exceed **500 MB**? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: avoid fastai as it has many dependencies; you are good to use the raw libs due to space restrictions!

Comment: @Aditya , using fastai makes the source code small and it is easy to use. That's why I use it. And I cannot really use the latest versions, because they exceed permitted limit.

Comment: Yep! I know what fastAI is but as I said, the requirements are little high for it. Why don't you try a smaller model?

Comment: @Aditya Model is not a bottleneck. It's less than 90 MB.

Comment: I solved this by looking at the requirements file of other people who deployed in similar conditions.

Comment: Cool! Can you attach a sample as an answer as well?

Comment: Okay, wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Till now, what I have learned is that it is a trial and error process.

And the best solution is to look for projects that have already done this using a working combination of libraries.

I used this `requirements.txt` file, which works fine:

```
gunicorn
flask
numpy
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
torchvision==0.2.2
fastai==1.0.52
jupyter
```

The web app works perfectly and the permitted size is not exceeded.

Although Heroku's size limit is 500 MB, they have a *soft limit* of 300 MB. These libraries, their dependencies, and the model file together exceed that resulting in a slightly longer response time.